# The picker doesn't update the number of segments it has when a value is changed during execution

Tags: xcode, swiftui, picker

I have recently started learning swiftUI and I'm facing some issues here. This is the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var measurementType = 0
    @State private var inputValue = ""
    @State private var inputUnit = 0
    @State private var outputUnit = 1

    var outputValue = ""
    let measurementTypes = ["Temp", "Length", "Time", "Volume"]
    
    
    var typeDictionary = [
        ["Celsius", "Fahrenheit", "Kelvin"],
        ["Meters", "Kilometers", "Feet", "Yards", "Miles"],
        ["Seconds", "Minutes", "Hours", "Days"],
        ["Milliliters", "Liters", "Cups", "Pints", "Gallons"]
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Choose the type of measurement")) {
                    Picker("The type of measurement", selection: $measurementType) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< measurementTypes.count) {
                            Text("\(measurementTypes[$0])")
                        }
                    }
                    .id(measurementType)
                    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                }
                
                Section {
                    TextField("Enter the value", text: $inputValue)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Choose the input unit")) {
                    Picker("The input unit", selection: self.$inputUnit) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< typeDictionary[measurementType].count) {
                            Text("\(typeDictionary[measurementType][$0])")
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Choose the output unit")) {
                    
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Converted Value")) {
                    Text("")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Whenever I change the measurementType while the code is running, the values of the picker in the input units section update, but the number of segments don't. If I start with the value of measurementType as 1, then the app simply crashes when I choose Temp or Time from the picke.

Answer (score 1):

When using ForEach, you need to provide an id so SwiftUI can uniquely identify each element in the array and know when to redraw the view. You can use `id: \.self` to use the item's value as its id.

Here's an updated working version:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var measurementType = 0
    @State private var inputValue = ""
    @State private var inputUnit = 0
    @State private var outputUnit = 1

    var outputValue = ""
    let measurementTypes = ["Temp", "Length", "Time", "Volume"]
    
    
    var typeDictionary = [
        ["Celsius", "Fahrenheit", "Kelvin"],
        ["Meters", "Kilometers", "Feet", "Yards", "Miles"],
        ["Seconds", "Minutes", "Hours", "Days"],
        ["Milliliters", "Liters", "Cups", "Pints", "Gallons"]
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Choose the type of measurement")) {
                    Picker("The type of measurement", selection: $measurementType) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< measurementTypes.count, id: \.self) {
                            Text("\(measurementTypes[$0])")
                        }
                    }
                    .id(measurementType)
                    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                }
                
                Section {
                    TextField("Enter the value", text: $inputValue)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Choose the input unit")) {
                    Picker("The input unit", selection: self.$inputUnit) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< typeDictionary[measurementType].count, id: \.self) {
                            Text("\(typeDictionary[measurementType][$0])")
                        }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Choose the output unit")) {
                    
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Converted Value")) {
                    Text("")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```